# Gnuplot palette setting scale values

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following code:

```
unset key

set autoscale
set logscale x

#                                   yellow         red         darkred
set palette model RGB defined ( 1 '#FFFF00', 12 '#FF0000', 13 '#8B0000' )

set terminal epslatex
set size 1.25,0.75


set cbrange [1:13]
set output "figs/plot.tex"
plot 'data/d1.csv' using 1:($2**2):(10*$3/m):3 with points pt 7 ps variable palette, \
     'data/d2.csv' using 1:($2**2) with points pt 2 ps 2 lc 'black' lw 5
```

The ticks on the palette on the side of the plot go form 2 to 12 but I want it to go from 1 to 13 (so that both the min and max are marked). The data min=1 and max=12.5. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add 1 and 13 as additional tics, you can use

```
set cbtics add (1, 13)
```

For tics at 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 use

```
set cbtics 1,3
```

Comment: Reset this with `set cbtics auto`.